# How do I stop all animations and show a sequence of sprites on the screen?

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am implementing a tutorial mode for my cocos2d(-iphone v2.0) platformer/running game - when the user is in tutorial mode, I need to pause the game and provide instructions. In the game, there is a point where I need to stop all animations and provide some inputs to the user in sequence, overwriting each other (spaced 1 second apart, say).

at the required point, within my game layer, I call `[[CCDirector sharedDirector]stopAnimation]` which stops all animations. Now, I want to call two successive calls, spaced apart by 1 second. I don't get any update calls since animation is stopped. So, I try to use an NSTimer as shown below:

```
-(void)update
{
  //...
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector]stopAnimation];
  //...
  [self showFirstTutorialInstruction];
  NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
  target:self
  selector:@selector(showNextTutorialInstruction)
  userInfo:nil
  repeats:NO]retain];
  //...
}

-(void)ccTouchBegan(...)
{
  //...
  [CCDirector sharedDirector]startAnimation];
  //...
}
```

Now the animation gets stopped, timer function does get called, but the second instruction in the selector is not displayed in the display area until after I restart animation. How do I get the second instruction in `showNextTutorialInstruction` to display as soon as it is called? I have tried forcing a visit of the layer, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How is your update method written to provide your movements/animation? One thing you could do is instead of using stopAnimation you can use pause. For Example I tried this in a test project

```
-(void)startPause {
    if(!isPaused) {
        isPaused = YES;
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
        [self performSelector:@selector(addLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    } else {
        isPaused = NO;
        [self removeChild:addLabel cleanup:YES];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    }
}

-(void)addLabel {
    addLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"TEST" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:20];
    [self addChild:addLabel];
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    addLabel.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
}
```

the [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]; is outlined in the cocos2d documentation as "Pauses the running scene. The running scene will be *drawed* but all scheduled timers will be paused While paused, the draw rate will be 4 FPS to reduce CPU consuption"

the isPaused I used is a BOOL where in my update method at the very beginning I have the line

```
if (isPaused) { return; }
```

but looking back at it now you shouldnt need that at all. Since the timer in my performSelector is added after the director is paused it will run as scheduled. This should enable you to get the desired result of adding what you need.